# jQuery UI Datepicker not working | jQuery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this project about booking system in php. little bit old tbh but it's get the job done

Anyway.. I have a problem with the "datepicker" in jquery.

I have this input field

```
<div class="booking_dropdown"><input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker" placeholder="Check in" name="arrival" required="required" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['arrival']) ? $_POST['arrival'] :date('m/d/Y');?>"></div>
```

with I connected with the datepicker function

here it's code

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    startDate: new Date(),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate: 0
});
```

the `mineDate: 0` suppose to make the booking mechanism start from current day and disable all the past days, but actually the whole datepicker function turned out to be not working at all. idk why tbh

Note : the function located in another file called `index.html` and the input field located in file called `template.php`

[Project Download Link](https://www.sourcecodester.com/download-code?nid=13492&title=Online+Hotel+Reservation+System+in+PHP%2FMySQLi+with+Source+Code)

Comment: So are you saying, if you remove that `minDate` property from the config object, the datepicker works? What does the browser console have to say, anything in there? (Maybe you made more typos in there, you wrote `mineDate` here in the description already.)

Comment: _"suppose to make the booking masochism start from current day"_ - mechanism. _Masochism_ is something completely different altogether :-)

Comment: I'm sorry about the wrong word
My english is so bad
I meant mechanism

answering to your question, if I removed the ```minDate``` it's also not working

Comment: _"the function located in another file called index.html and the input field located in file called template.php"_ - and how are those two files related? Is one embedding the other, does one request the other on the client side, ...? And please do not refer us to your download link now, to figure that out - all the _relevant_ information we need to reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question (in text form & properly formatted), not just a link to an external platform - [ask], [mre]

Comment: @CBroe

https://imgur.com/a/PLiSKZR

this is the errors I got in the console

Comment: So you did not manage to embed the datepicker library script itself correctly yet, then you can't expect any code that wants to use it to work either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It appears, from your image of the error, that you are using Bootstrap. Upon review, I do see that jQuery Datepicker is loading: `<script src="<?php echo WEB_ROOT;?>plugins/jquery-datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>` you later load the BootStrap DatePicker: `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>` So I Would review the documentation for this library.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty, ok I will try to review and fix the issue if possible. Thanks